Версионирование записей БД
Я выбрал подход к реализации версионирования записей через составной первичный ключ (id int, version int). Однако это не только значительно изменило и усложнило логику запросов, увеличило и усложнило модели sqlalchemy, но и озадачило меня вопросом:

Как мне сделать так, чтобы some_column мог повторяться для одного и того же id, но не пересекался между разными id? Красным показано то, какое значение не должно вставляться



В реальной практике чаще самостоятельно реализуют версионирование или используют готовые библиотеки наподобие SQLAlchemy-Continuum?


несвязанные вопросы следует задавать отдельными вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

@aleksandrbarakin, stackoverflow не дает публиковать чаще одного вопроса в 40 минут. Поэтому жду

Будет ли лучше использовать готовую библиотеку на подобие SQLAlchemy-Continuum? - вот в такой формулировке спрашивать и не стоит: вопрос будет закрыт как не имеющий объективно верного ответа.

@aleksandrbarakin, спасибо, исправил

Как разработчик БД с 30-летним стажем, могу с сочувствием констатировать уровень геморроя, который Вы пытаетесь себе создать. Вся эта идея - грубейшая ошибка в идеологии проектирования базы данных. Потом никто уже не разгребёт.

@FoxFox, а можете подсказать куда копать? Был бы очень благодарен

@FoxFox, возможно ли с Вами как-то связаться? Был бы рад взять платную консультацию

Я в Украине. Занимаюсь бизнесом выборочно. Тут особо обсуждать нечего. Прежде, чем что-то делать, я задаю себе вопрос: а надо ли? Может я глупо спланировал? В чём суть такой необходимости в версионировании и так ли это надо? А может надо версии вовремя отправлять? Или сделать пользователей вменяемыми? Насколько модель реляционна? Правильно ли установлены связи один-к-одному и один-ко-многим? Что такое в данном случае версии и почему они возникают? Версии чего? Что будет дальше?

Есть также термины, которые не соответствуют терминам баз данных, например, "но не пересекался между разными id". Понять это не могу. При добавлении записей надо контролировать возможность их добавления, проектирование базы ни при чём. Если я не могу добавить запись, состоящую из 2 2 A, это надо просто пресекать в фазе добавления. Кроме того, пишутся процедуры проверки правильности базы данных и статистика. Когда в базе миллионы записей надо это делать - формировать статистику по группам записей в зависимости от полей. То, чем Вы занимаетесь, мне не пришло бы даже в голову, решил бы это проще
